# Why am I getting a "None" at the end of the output while computing textwrap module in Python?

Tags: python, string, word-wrap

Although I am defining my function as below:

```
import textwrap

def wrap(string, max_width):
    print(textwrap.fill(string, max_width))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    string, max_width = input(), int(input())
    result = wrap(string, max_width)
    print(result)
```

I am getting an error like:

```
*ABCD
EFGH
IJKL
IMNO
QRST
UVWX
YZ
None*
```

Can you please help me to debug why this "None" or how is this value getting augmented with the output.

Comment: What's s and w? Pls be more specific.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces the output you show. When I run your code, I get an error because `textwrap` is undefined.

Comment: Most likely you get `None` because `textwrap.fill()` does not have a `return` statement so it returns `None` by default which is then printed by the `print()` call in the `wrap` function you show here.

Comment: Yeah, I made the code more specific and clear now. @Stqrosta

Comment: This is just the classic "function without an explicit return returns none" issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing twice.
Once in the function, and then again the return value of the function. The `None` is coming from the second print.

Do this:

```
import textwrap

def wrap(string, max_width):
    return textwrap.fill(string, max_width) # return , don't print

if __name__ == '__main__':
    string, max_width = input().rstrip(), int(input())
    result = wrap(string, max_width)
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to retun the result:

this should work:

```
import textwrap

def wrap(string, max_width):
    return(textwrap.fill(string, max_width))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    string, max_width = input(), int(input())
    result = wrap(string, max_width)
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

`wrap()` does not have an explicit `return`. By default it returns `None`. So the value of `result` is `None`. Just get rid of the `result` variable and the following `print()` to fix it. Alternatively, change `wrap()` to return the result instead of printing it.